# chemical equilibrium and activity

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics

Here is a graph of equilibrium coeff in various salt concentrations in water.

[image]

Lets take the example $\ce{BaSO4}$.

Now as we are increasing the salt concentration in water, the following reaction is moving towards right as eq. coeff is increasing.

$$\ce{BaSO4 -> Ba^2+ + SO4^2-}$$

Now I am really confused on why as I am increasing more salt to water, the above reaction is creating more ions. So basically the more ionic the aqueous environment is, greater the generation of ions of Barium Sulphate. But isn't it bit anti-intuitive. Why the system is creating more ions (i.e. increasing K) when water already has increasing number of ions from table salt?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Keep CH SE Q titles in plain text.

Comment: Search for activity coefficient and Debye-Hückel equation, e.g. on Wikipedia.

Comment: It's called "salting in".  Remember, pure water ionizes very little.

Answer (score 1):

- The $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ ions will surround by anions
- The $\ce{SO_4^{2-}}$ will be surrounded by cations

So they stabilize a lot more actually. Remember that this may take long, but thermodynamically that is probably a stable situation (i.e system lowers the energy).

But it does reach a limit and plateau at some point.

This is quite general as you can see.

Answer (score -3):

You intuition is telling you that ions should suppress more ions from coming into solution and that is probably correct and were it the only thing happening it should be observed. In fact it is. Almost all ionic compounds have solubility limits. This is usually attributed to equal rates of dissolution and crystallization, but your intuitive explanation is probably just as good. Lets take a closer look at what is going on. The crystal has a lattice energy that must be supplied to dissolve it; the solvent has intermolecular attractions that must be disrupted, again requiring energy. [This is ignoring the entropy changes disrupting and rearranging order in both, in the end free energy changes are pertinent.] The energy requirements are supplied by the solvation of the ions; solvation releases energy. Ions entering solution can be solvated by solvent molecules, but would it not be nicer to have an ion of the opposite charge available to greet you? This is what is happening. This is sometimes attributed to an increase in dielectric constant but in the end it all comes down to the interaction of molecules and ions. Notice that the effect of ionic strength increase is much greater for the divalent ions of BaSO4 than the monovalent ions. I would not be surprised if the effect of ionic strength were not related to the crystal lattice energy. I have just given you a project. Report back.

Comment: This quickly got 3 downvotes Are there specific reasons? Please help me if I am violating some thing or if you think the chemistry is incorrect.

Comment: 3 downvotes means that 3 individuals came to the conclusion that "This answer is not useful". If you are "violating some thing", the answer would probably be deleted. "Very low quality" is also a reason for deletion.

Comment: I did not down-vote, but I do have some comments. You could break up the text into paragraphs, one for each separate point or idea. You could focus on the effect of the presence of other ions. As you get to the core of the question, you switch from technical language to colloquial, "... nicer to have an ion of the opposite charge available to greet you?". The last three sentences don't seem to be part of an answer.

Comment: And the gibberish of the previous answer met any qualifications? "This is quite general as you can see"! I tried to answer in the language of the questioner and the last sentences are pertinent. The common approach is the effect of dielectric constant. the difference in the charge on the ions is paramount and the questioner should be encouraged to think more about the Chemistry. It's  called "salting  in"! that is used to make ice cream in the summer[after a hailstorm]

Comment: I was not comparing answers. I was giving some suggestions how you might improve this answer because your comment said "please help me". Usually, if I feel none of the answers fully address the questions, and if I find the question interesting, and if I have some time, I try to write a better answer myself rather than criticizing the other answers.

Comment: Um, you add halite to water and ice to decrease the freezing point of the water. It's not what "salting in" means.

Comment: Salting in  a highly technical term. It is usually used to decrease solubility of organic salts or organic compounds in water. that is discussed in my first three sentences. I was joking about the ice cream but if given the opportunity you should try it. I think my answer fully addressed the question. the final statements were to help the questioner to think more deeply about it, then maybe they might read about Debye -Huckel treatment.